# Converting Gamut3D from RGB colorspace to LAB colorspace

Tags: matlab, color

I have this code for Gamut3D in `RGB`, but I'm looking to convert it into `LAB` colorspace but I'm not really sure what changes I should be making.

```
rgbImage = imread('pill1.jpg');
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 3.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
% Display the original color image.
imshow(rgbImage);
title('Original Color Image');
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
% Extract the individual red, green, and blue color channels.
redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
blueChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 3);
% Construct the 3D color gamut.
gamut3D = zeros(256,256,256);
for column = 1: columns
        for row = 1 : rows
                rIndex = redChannel(row, column) + 1;
                gIndex = greenChannel(row, column) + 1;
                bIndex = blueChannel(row, column) + 1;
                gamut3D(rIndex, gIndex, bIndex) = gamut3D(rIndex, gIndex, bIndex) + 1;
        end
end
% Get a list of non-zero colors so we can put it into scatter3()
% so that we can visualize the colors that are present.
r = zeros(256, 1);
g = zeros(256, 1);
b = zeros(256, 1);
nonZeroPixel = 1;
for red = 1 : 256
        for green = 1: 256
                for blue = 1: 256
                        if (gamut3D(red, green, blue) > 1)
                                % Record the RGB position of the color.
                                r(nonZeroPixel) = red;
                                g(nonZeroPixel) = green;
                                b(nonZeroPixel) = blue;
                                nonZeroPixel = nonZeroPixel + 1;
                        end
                end
        end
end
figure;
scatter3(r, g, b, 3);
xlabel('R' );
ylabel('G' );
zlabel('B' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The so-called `Gamut` in the code, is nothing but a 3d color histogram. Colors from the image are collected into it, and then each unique `(r,g,b)` is being shown as a scatter point.

In order to show the distribution of the colors in `LAB` space, you can convert your image from `sRGB` to `LAB`, (Assuming that the image is in `sRGB` space) and then run the same procedure that you have now.

In order to convert it, use:

```
    cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    labImage = applycform(cform, rgbImage);
```

---

By the way, the code in your question can be optimized into 4 lines:

```
    im = imread('peppers.png');
    im = reshape(im,[],3);
    im = unique(im,'rows');
    scatter3(im(:,1),im(:,2),im(:,3));
```

Comment: That's good to know. But what if I wanted to cluster them together something like what's been done on here. I wish to view them similar to what's been done on this blog http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/12/23/two-dimensional-histograms/ , but not sure what changes I should be making.